# Pandas DataFrames to_latex: how to fit tables on a page?

Tags: python, python-2.7, latex, pandas

I'm trying to use the pandas `to_latex()` function to create PDFs with my tables on them, but every time I try I get an

> Overfull \hbox (914.42409pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--43

or similar error. I know this is because my tables are too big for the page, my question is, how do I make my tables smaller? Documentation for the `to_latex` function seems to not be very extensive, so I my searches for a solution haven't been very fruitful.

My code for creating the table and .tex file is like this:

```
r = r.to_latex(na_rep = '0', float_format = fp(2),  formatters=format_dict)
message = "\documentclass[12pt]{article}" \
      "\\"+"begin{document} " \
      "\section{20 Day Trading Stats}"
footer = "\end{document}"
message = message + r + footer
afile=open("outputfile.tex", "wb")
afile.write(message)
```

where `fp(2)` and `format_dict` are just format specifications for the parameters.

I'm using MikTeX and LEd for building the PDFs, if it matters, and my PC is running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be [matrix2latex](https://code.google.com/p/matrix2latex/). This module allows you to put your tabular in any type of environment you'd like. Typically, I'd go for:

```
from matrix2latex import matrix2latex
import numpy
data = numpy.array(r)
matrix2latex(data, 'outputfile.tex', 'table', 'tabular', 'small')
```

which would result in:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cc...cc}
\toprule
\begin{small}
item1 & item2 &..... \\
...
\end{small}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Obviously, you can change 'small' to anything you'd like, just keep in mind that the order of your arguments is important.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to your problem could be adding \small inside \begin{table}. You can do so with the following code:

```
df.to_latex(
        os.path.join("file.tex"),
        caption="My caption",
        label="tab:subject_info",
        escape=False,
        column_format="cccccccccccccccc",
        index=False,
    )

with open("file.tex"), "r+") as f:
    text = f.read().replace("\\begin{tabular}", "\small \\begin{tabular}")
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
```